# Where do you find the Serial number for the built in Chromecast on Nvidia Shield?

Tags: android, nvidia, chromecast

Hey i am working at a place, where we test specific builts for Chromecast, and as one of the few employees i am the owner of a Nvidia Shield rather then a Chromecast. So if we provide the Serial number for the Chromecast, we will recieve the dev build.

So my question is where do i find this serial number for the shield, and is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Cast registration documentation does a great job of explaining the requirements and processes involved in registering your device.
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration#devices

They have specific functionality that allows you to select a cast target, and then once you have selected a target it will display the serial number on the attached screen, I have used this multiple times myself.

> Copied from the documentation linked above.
>
> *From the drop-down menu, select the device for which you want to obtain the serial number. For Chromecast and Android TV devices, the serial number displays on the TV screen and plays aloud on the TV speakers. For Cast for audio devices, the serial number plays aloud on the Cast for audio device speakers.*